# python. Что использовать для изменения состояния объекта с клавиатуры?

Tags: python, многопоточность, процесс, распараллеливание

Условия:
Есть объект, хранящий свое состояние. Одна ветвь программы проверяет состояние и в зависимости от него делает что-то, не важно что. Вторая ветвь должна ожидать ввод с клавиатуры, и на определенную комбинацию символов должна поменять состояние объекта (при этом ожидается, что первая ветвь изменит свое поведение, обнаружив изменившееся состояние).

Вопрос: 
Чем это реализовать? В идеале еще подскажите, как? Под ветвями наверное подразумеваются процессы. Я еще новичок в Питоне, так что куда ни копну - нужно потратить немало времени на изучение того, что окажется неподходящим для этой задачи.

Сами методы и объект у меня уже написаны, но, как понимаю, их надо запихнуть в тред (процесс?), и как-то реализовать параллельное пассивное ожидание ввода с клавиатуры (и его обработку).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я разобралась.

Создается один поток (thread), который слушает ввод. Здесь важно, что весь ввод желательно реализовывать только в одном потоке, ибо input() блокирует потоки и получается каша. При нужном вводе меняется состояние объекта, что в целом просто.

Другой поток, созданный тогда, когда удобно, в бесконечном цикле проверяет состояние объекта, и когда оно изменилось на нужное, начинает выполнять свою ветку.

Именно такой ответ я ждала несколько дней назад. Если кому-то будет интересно, как я это реализовала, то вот ссылка на гит: https://github.com/AlinaMalinaA/ElevatorSystem